# Efficiently creating and storing all "valid" edge combinations of all sizes from a set of edges

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, combinatorics, traveling-salesman

I think this is a fairly difficult question.  So thank you ahead of time for any help.

I have a graph I am traversing, creating different paths, one at a time.
I have a set of edges I "must" use, each is stored as a tuple of (to, from).  I am avoiding repeat nodes, so we only go to each "to" once, and to each "from" once.  I also don't want to create a cycle in the combination.

I want to create all combinations (where order matters) of edges.  To be specific, I want all combinations of all valid sizes of tuples.

Some examples for clarity:

```
Valid combinations of edges:

((5,7))
((3,9),(9,11),(21,18))
((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5))

Invalid combinations:
((9,8),(9,6))
((2,5),(11,3),(8,5))
((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1))
```

So, one thing we can see, is that to make all combinations, we will make combinations of size 1, then of size 2, then of 3, ... 4....n

Don't worry, it's not quite this insane.  The amount of edges I am creating combinations with is typically not that many.  But it is variable, and who knows, maybe I could end up creating some combinations of size n.

So, I was thinking about using itertools to generate the combinations.  I could put itertools combinations in a loop, and increment the size of the combinations of each pass.

But then I realized, that it is likely that the majority of combinations will actually end up invalid, and if I use itertools I don't think I can check their validity until the entire combination has been generated.  This seems incredibly inefficient.

So, my thinking then went to using an adjacency list, where any edge (to, from) I want to force is stored in indices [to][from].  This allows me to iterate the adjacency list such that I avoid getting duplicate "to"s or duplicate "froms".

However, I still can't conceptualize how I can actually write a function that generates all of the combinations I want through traversal of the adjacency list.

Any Ideas?

Note:  For now, I don't mind if anyone chooses to ignore the challenge of avoiding closed cycles, ie: 1,2,3,4,1

Comment: Shouldn't it be `((3,9),(9,11),(11,18))`

Comment: I think it may be helpful to start back at the root problem and explain that more thoroughly. For example, what it means when you say that you 'must use' these 'edges' when creating these 'paths'. I understand the efficiency problem with generating combinations, but am having a hard time understanding the overall goal.

Comment: @roganjosh  By meaning that I must use them, it means I must form a path that uses them.  So, when I select edges in my cycle, I must use one of the combinations out of all of my combinations I need to "force".  I take out that combination, and all the edges therein must be used in that path.  As for why I elaborated that I store them as a tuple of "to, from", it's because I want to convey the idea that my path selection is based upon connecting edges (_, a) with (a, _)   such that we create a cycle by connecting each to with a from.

Comment: @sytech  I understand that what I am trying to accomplish with this probably seems confusing.  I don't really want to try to explain my entire algorithm, but a good way to think about it is using a greedy TSP algorithm, and then based on a criteria picking edges, and then running the greedy algorithm again but forcing combinations of those edges.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  no - the example I gave is what I wanted to give.  Your example would also be a valid combination.  But I showed ((3,9),(9,11),(21,18)) because I wanted to demonstrate that a valid combination does not need to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a recursive generator function. It preprocesses the edges list into an adjacency dict. It will produce all paths of length `l`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# preprocess for better performance
edges = [(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,7), (3,9),(9,11),(11,18)]
graph = defaultdict(set)
for f, t in edges:
    graph[f].add(t)

def paths(graph, l, fr=None, avoid=None):
    avoid = avoid or set()  # avoid previous nodes
    if l == 0:  # base case: empty path
        yield ()
    from_nodes = [fr] if fr else graph.keys()
    for f in from_nodes:
        new_avoid = avoid | set([f])  # set union
        for t in graph[f]:  # for every adjacent node t...
            if t not in avoid:  # unless it has been seen
                # take all paths starting at t with length l-1
                for path in paths(graph, l-1, fr=t, avoid=new_avoid):
                    # and prepend the current edge
                    yield ((f, t),) + path 

>>> list(paths(graph, 2))
[((1, 2), (2, 3)),
 ((2, 3), (3, 9)),  # no cycle: ((1, 2), (2, 1))
 ((2, 3), (3, 4)),
 ((3, 9), (9, 11)),
 ((3, 4), (4, 5)),
 ((4, 5), (5, 7)),
 ((9, 11), (11, 18))]

>>> list(paths(graph, 3))
[((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 9)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)),
 ((2, 3), (3, 9), (9, 11)),
 ((2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)),
 ((3, 9), (9, 11), (11, 18)),
 ((3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7))]
```

Comment: I wanted to thank you.  With some minor editing I was able to create a fantastic recursive solution that exactly fit my needs.